# Log4j Grails how to configuring controllers at a log level?

Tags: grails, log4j, controllers

What different between `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet` and `grails.app.controllers`?
It seems that both of them can configuring  controllers.
`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet` not work ,
`grails.app.controllers` work ...

Comment: What is your grails version?

Answer (score 0):

> What different between org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet and
>   grails.app.controllers?

`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet` applies to classes in the Grails framework.  `grails.app.controllers` applies to controllers in your application or plugin (until Grails 3.3 when we got rid of that prefix for the logger names).